# No contact created in MongoDB when session is closed

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, mongodb

8.2 update 0. I have changed session to be 1 minute instead of the default 20 minutes. When I log into the site, in incognito, surf around and close the browser. No contact is ever created in the Mongo analytics database.

[image]

When I look in the logs, there is nothing before or after the profile is created to identify any issues. I have installed a profile viewer and can verify that a profile is being created and has custom facets. I just can get it to write the contact to Mongo when the session is closed.

I have tried several different browers on and off server.

Comment: Can you post code showing how you identify and or create the user?

Comment: Just normal Sitecore xDB. I just did a SIM site, xDB worked. Deployed my code, no xDB. Removed App_Config changes, xDB works. Now to find the config file causing the issue.

Comment: oh I see, your contact collection isn't even being created. You'll want to make sure the config that sets up the Contact Repository is enabled. Um, I think it's the Sitecore.Analytics....... I don't recall, but definitely in that family.

Comment: Is the [VisitorIdentification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120608/is-html-sitecore-visitoridentification-required-with-sitecore-8-mvc) code available on layout? `<ensureSessionContext patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config">` this pipeline is responsible for creating the contact if it helps.

Comment: You're dead on @phani. Post that as a question and I'll mark it answered. Keep believe I forgot that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know you have already found the exact solution for your particular case. Still, I'm going to list the steps I normally take when troubleshooting data saving issues in xDB. Hopefully, this can help others in the future.

1. Ensure the `analytics` connection string is set up properly in the ***ConnectionStrings.config***.
2. Make sure that you have a valid xDB license. You can see the list of available licenses in the Control Panel > Administration > Installed licenses. "Sitecore.xDB.base" should be present there.
3. Make sure that xDB and its tracking subsystem are enabled. The settings `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` should be set to `true` when you open this page: `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx`.
4. The configuration file `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.config` should be enabled.
5. Enable tracking on your site definition by setting `enableTracking` to `true` for your site in the `<sites>` section.
6. Try making several page requests instead of just one before letting the session expire.
7. Ensure that all of your layout pages contain the `VisitorIdentification` control in the `<head>` section.

   - In MVC layouts, use `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()`;
   - in ASP.NET WebForms layouts, use `<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />`.
8. Try disabling robot detection by setting both `Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots` and `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` to `false`. The original values for these settings are located in the ***Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config***. If interactions are saved after this, it means your visitors were recognized as robots.
9. If nothing helps, go through the steps listed in the article [**Troubleshooting xDB data issues**](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445).

Comment: @dnstommy mark this as answer. This has detailed explanation on what and all to be checked for your question.

Answer (score 4):

Ensure the [VisitorIdentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120608/is-html-sitecore-visitoridentification-required-with-sitecore-8-mvc) code is available on the layout.

```
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

Also, if it helps, the contact creation logic is executed in the below pipeline processor:

```
<ensureSessionContext>
...
  <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.CreateContact, Sitecore.Analytics">
    <ContactManager ref="tracking/contactManager" />
  </processor>
...
</ensureSessionContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple more steps that were missing in my particular scenario:

1. The **Global.asax** file must inherit from **Sitecore.Web.Application**:

   ```
   <%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>
   ```
2. If using **Global.asax.cs** instead, follow the same inheritance structure:

   ```
   public class Global : Sitecore.Web.Application
   {
       protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }
   }
   ```
3. For testing purposes it's helpful to reduce the session timeout in **Web.config**:

   ```
   <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1">
   ```

I've found the Global.asax tip in an article on [Creating a Visual Studio Project for Sitecore MVC](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/sitecore-mvc/creating-project/).

Answer (score -1):

If you have enabled tracker then you should be able to see values stored in MongoDB. But few steps you need to verify again.

1. Check both settings enabled in **Sitecore.Xdb.config**:

   ```
   setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" 

   setting name="Xdb.Tracking.Enabled" value="true"
   ```
2. ClusterName and Hostname should be Unique Name/Host Name in **Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config**:

   ```
   setting name="Analytics.ClusterName" value="siteName"

   setting name="Analytics.HostName" value="siteName"
   ```
3. After making sure all steps configured you can also [try my blog](https://pramisoni.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/sitecore-analytics-tracking-on-click-of-events/) for further steps to push data in contact DB.