# What are the steps I could take to debug non-functioning Experience Analytics (MongoDB)?

Tags: experience-analytics, mongodb

On one of the websites I'm working on the Site Analytics are broken - a MongoDB database is successfully created by Sitecore to store Analytics data and I can see the Analytics interface in Content Editor, but no visit data is actually recorded in MongoDB. I've found a [short guideline](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445) from Sitecore itself, but it wasn't particularly useful. I couldn't identify any particular errors from the logs, so I'm a bit clueless as to how to proceed.

What are the steps I could take to debug my Analytics Data issue? I know this is a bit too broad, but I presume there aren't too many fail points.

Comment: Have you tried following the answers to this question? http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko thank you, no I did not. I will give it a try.

Comment: Did you check if your mongo services are running or not? And if they are then check the mongodb error logs. Also checkout this blog post https://mrunaldaftari.wordpress.com/2017/02/16/conquer-mongodb-errors-like-a-pro/