# Sitecore Contact expires using out of process session handling

Tags: session-state, contact-facets

In a Sitecore 8.1 Update 3, we have configured the mongodb for shared session state into "Session" collection, and analytics is configured separately into its own collection as well.  The code is configured to preserve obtained location data into a custom facet.  That data is recalled between browser sessions to allow the site visitor (anonymously) to recall its location settings.
I have confirmed that rebooting iis site, the SC_Analytics_Global_Cookie value is preserved, and the facet is deserialized and location data is accessible.  However, after about 20min or so, of inactivity (closing browser) the value of the cookie still stays the same, but I no longer see the location data.

Is there an expiration set up for "unidentified" contact within Sitecore?

Here is the code i use to recall the Location data. IGeoTracker is a child interface of the IFacet.

```
ITracker current = Tracker.Current;
if (((current == null) || !current.IsActive) || (current.Contact == null))
{
   SetLocationUnknown();
}
else
{
   IGeoTracker facet = current.Contact.GetFacet<IGeoTracker>(this._geoTrackerFacetName);
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(facet.FormatedAddress))
   {
      string formatedAddress = facet.FormatedAddress;
      SetLocationKnown(formatedAddress);
 ...
   }
   else
   {
      SetLocationUnknown();
   }
}
```

**Update**

I have been doing a bit of reverse engineering with dotPeek tool, and deduced that the ShareSessionStateManger is designed to be 1 minute longer than a private session state timeout which is defined in the web config. Either way  the shared session state store is not designed to persist the contact data indefinitely.
Per further research, the contact data must make it back into the Analytics database. That's when I validated that Contact is not being written back into the Analytics Collection.  The default Sitecore configuration actually uses a stub contact repository class which prevents the persistence of analytics data.  To enable that, we must deploy the configuration in *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.config*

```
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>   
   <commitSession>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.CheckPreconditions, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateGeoIpData, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.EnsureClassification, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateContactBehaviorProfiles, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.Robots, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.IgnoreVisitsWithoutPages, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateContactSaveMode, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.SubmitSession, Sitecore.Analytics" >
      <SessionContextManager ref="tracking/sessionContextManager" />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.ProcessSubscriptions, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.ReleaseSharedSession, Sitecore.Analytics" runIfAborted="true"/>
  </commitSession>

  <postSessionEnd>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.PostSessionEnd.CommitSession, Sitecore.Analytics" />
  </postSessionEnd>

  <submitSessionContext>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveDevice, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:before="*" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveClassificationsMap, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="*[1]" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveVisit, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="*[2]" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.RenumberInteractions, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveVisit, Sitecore.Analytics']" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.UpdateKeyBehaviorCache, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.RenumberVisitIndexes, Sitecore.Analytics']" >
      <ContactManager ref="tracking/contactManager" />
    </processor>
  </submitSessionContext>

</pipelines>

<submitQueue>
  <backgroundService type="Sitecore.Analytics.SubmitQueueService, Sitecore.Analytics">
    <!-- Service wakeup interval in seconds. -->
    <Interval>60</Interval>
  </backgroundService>
</submitQueue>

 <tracking>
   <contactManager type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true">
    <param desc="sharedSessionStateManager" ref="tracking/sharedSessionState/manager" />
    <param desc="contactRepository">
      <patch:delete />
    </param>
   </contactManager>
  </tracking>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Can you verify that the contact ID remains the same from session to session. And that the geoTracker data is in the Contact table, in Mongo. When the user rejoins the site after 20 minutes (session timeout), the contact is reloaded from Mongo, in the tracker.

Comment: @ChrisAuer The Contact ID in the cookie is the same.  Mongodb data in the shared session state is serialized as a binary object thus i cannot validate the location details in the facet there but i do see the entry under the same id/shared.  I do not see any entries under Analytics/Contacts table though. My understanding is that the visitor is never identified for some reason.  I do have sc:VisitorIdentification on my layout.

Comment: The Faceted data is saved to and read from the Contacts collection in the Sitecore Analytics Mongo database. Your issue wont be the session DB. It will be if the data is not being written to Mongo. Is IGeoTracker a custom class you built or is that a Sitecore class?

Comment: give this video a quick look. I hope it helps explain what I think is wrong. https://www.screencast.com/t/s7m2O6NMyQ

Comment: are all your Facets and Elements marked as [Serializable]? That might be the reason they are not bring saved to the xDB database.

Comment: @ChrisAuer actually, i think the facet data is in session db b/c i do not see a contact created under Analytics collection at all.  I am trying to deduce why that's the case.  I'll take a look at the video of course.  Also, all of the facet items are serializable to accommodate out of proc serialization requirements.

Comment: I had the same issue a while ago. Hopefully this helps. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/no-contact-created-in-mongodb-when-session-is-closed

Comment: @ChrisAuer  Thank you. I will review shortly.

Comment: @ChrisAuer  I really appreciate all of your insight. I have figured this issue out but could not have done it without you.

Comment: Thank you, glad I could help. Could you please post what you issue was? So the next person can be help also.

Comment: I posted the update in the bold.  But I can certianly create a separate entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing a bit of reverse engineering with dotPeek tool, and deduced that the ShareSessionStateManger is designed to be 1 minute longer than a private session state timeout which is defined in the web config. Either way  the shared session state store is not designed to persist the contact data indefinitely.
Per further research, the contact data must make it back into the Analytics database. That's when I validated that Contact is not being written back into the Analytics Collection.  The default Sitecore configuration actually uses a stub contact repository class which prevents the persistence of analytics data.  To enable that, we must deploy the configuration in *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.Database.config*

```
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>   
   <commitSession>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.CheckPreconditions, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateGeoIpData, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.EnsureClassification, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateContactBehaviorProfiles, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.Robots, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.IgnoreVisitsWithoutPages, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.UpdateContactSaveMode, Sitecore.Analytics" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.SubmitSession, Sitecore.Analytics" >
      <SessionContextManager ref="tracking/sessionContextManager" />
    </processor>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.ProcessSubscriptions, Sitecore.Analytics"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.ReleaseSharedSession, Sitecore.Analytics" runIfAborted="true"/>
  </commitSession>

  <postSessionEnd>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.PostSessionEnd.CommitSession, Sitecore.Analytics" />
  </postSessionEnd>

  <submitSessionContext>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveDevice, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:before="*" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveClassificationsMap, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="*[1]" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveVisit, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="*[2]" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.RenumberInteractions, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.SaveVisit, Sitecore.Analytics']" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.UpdateKeyBehaviorCache, Sitecore.Analytics" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.SubmitSessionContext.RenumberVisitIndexes, Sitecore.Analytics']" >
      <ContactManager ref="tracking/contactManager" />
    </processor>
  </submitSessionContext>

</pipelines>

<submitQueue>
  <backgroundService type="Sitecore.Analytics.SubmitQueueService, Sitecore.Analytics">
    <!-- Service wakeup interval in seconds. -->
    <Interval>60</Interval>
  </backgroundService>
</submitQueue>

 <tracking>
   <contactManager type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager, Sitecore.Analytics" singleInstance="true">
    <param desc="sharedSessionStateManager" ref="tracking/sharedSessionState/manager" />
    <param desc="contactRepository">
      <patch:delete />
    </param>
   </contactManager>
  </tracking>
</sitecore>
```