# Mongo db Interactions table not getting updated

Tags: xdb, mongodb

In my dev machine I am not getting any interactions added in interaction table of mongo db. My session state entry in web.config is as follows:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Both in mongo db and sql tables like `Fact_PageViews` values are not getting updated.
 I tried to copy `App_Config` and `web.config` from another machine where interactions are getting loaded, still interactions are not getting updated.
I have tried solutions given in links like sitecore [community](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/9/t/2987) but still got no luck.
Please give me some suggestions on how I can get it working.

**Note:** I have tried recycling app pool to get data into mongo db but no data was added.

Comment: What version of Sitecore? 8.2 Update 3 and above no longer track anonymous users by default. http://www.waitingimpatiently.com/tracking-anonymous-users-in-xdb-post-8-2-update-3/

Comment: Also gibe this accepted answer a read. It has solved these issues more than a few times. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/no-contact-created-in-mongodb-when-session-is-closed

Comment: @ChrisAuer I am using sitecore 8.1 rev 151207. I will read the question and update.Thanks..

Comment: @Anjo- Is this still an issue?

Comment: @AnkitJoshi still i am getting issue, but its not consistent. Sometimes data coming sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try:

1- Ensure mongodb is running. If configured as a service validate whether it's running properly

2- Check that your /App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config file has been correctly updated to reference your Mongo instance and reporting database instance, and that they can be accessed from your Sitecore instance.

3- Ensure you have the `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` in the  section of your layout CSHTML file.

4- Make sure your Analytics is enabled. For Sitecore version 8.0 look for `<setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="true" />`. For versions 8.1+ look for `<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />`

if you still can't capture data I suggest reviewing these [link1](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com.br/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2015/10/Troubleshooting-Sitecore-8-XP-Analytics.aspx) and [link2](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445)